# Using dlfcn.h with a library containing static variables

Tags: c, dynamic-library

I'm working with `dlfcn.h` and I'm having an issue. I'm implementing a server (executable) that load clients (libraries).

The issue is that the client library has a static global variable and it seems that the address is the same when I load several times this same library.

Here is an example of code:

**The client**

(client.h)

```
struct player {
  // Few fields...
};
```

(client.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static struct player *pl;

void initialize() {
  pl = malloc(sizeof(struct player));
  printf("test_initialize, struct player address : %p\n", pl); // TEST

  // Some code...
}

void finalize() {
  printf("struct player address %p\n", pl);

  if (pl) {
    free_player(pl);
    printf("test_finalize\n");
  }
}
```

Note that I can't modify the `initialize()` and the `finalize()` procedures. There given and must be common (it's a student project).

**The server**

(server.h)

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct client {
  void *handle;
  void (*initialize)();
  void (*finalize)();
  // Few fields...
};

struct server {
  size_t nb_clients;
  struct client **loaded_clients;
};
```

(server.c)

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

struct client* load_client(char *path){
  struct client *client = malloc(sizeof(struct client));

  if(!client){
    return NULL;
  }

  client->handle = dlopen(path, RTLD_NOW); // RTLD_NOW seems to be the most appropriate. I've tested with RTLD_LAZY with no restult.

  printf("handle %d\n", *(int*)client->handle); // TEST

  if(!client->handle){
    free_client(client);
    client = NULL;
    return NULL;
  }

  client->initialize = dlsym(client->handle, "initialize");
  client->finalize = dlsym(client->handle, "finalize");

  client->initialize();

  // Some code...

  return client;
}

int load_clients(struct server *server, char **path, int nb_players){
  server->loaded_clients = malloc(nb_players * sizeof(struct client));

  if(!server->loaded_clients)
    return 0;

  server->nb_clients = nb_players;

  for(int i = 0; i < nb_players; i++){
    server->loaded_clients[i] = load_client(path[i]);

    server->loaded_clients[i]->player.id = i;
    server->loaded_clients[i]->player.nb_players = nb_players;
  }

  return 1;
}

void close_server(struct server *server){
  for (int i = 0; i < server->nb_clients; ++i)
    server->loaded_clients[i]->finalize();

  // Some code, freeing everything properly...
}
```

I compile the client library as `lib/libclient.so`.

**Testing code**

(test.c)

```
#include "../server/server.h"

#define NB_PLAYERS 3

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  char *path_lib[NB_PLAYERS] = {"lib/libclient.so", "lib/libclient.so", "lib/libclient.so"};
  struct server server;

  if(!load_clients(&server, path_libraries, nb_players)){
    return 1;
  }

  close_server(&server);

  return 0;
}
```

The result is :

```
handle -960790528
test_initialize, struct player address : 0xaed7a0
handle -960790528
test_initialize, struct player address : 0xaedd30
handle -960790528
test_initialize, struct player address : 0xaee2c0
struct player address 0xaee2c0
test_finalize
test_finalize
struct player address (nil)
struct player address (nil)
```

So it seems that the variable pl in the client is overwritten by the last malloc and the first two pl aren't accessible. Is there any alternative ?

Comment: DO NOT USE `malloc()` and global variables together, and if possible avoid global variables completely, unless it's the real and unique way to do something, and it never is. Because you can use `struct` and you can pass pointers to any function. `initialize()` should return the pointer and `finalize()` should take it as a parameter, and your code will be more robust and reliable and this problem will dissapear. Not to mention, that a function MUST be a reusable thing, and like you wrote them, they are not.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Thank you for your answer. Indeed, I can't edit the procedure of `initialize()` and `finalize()`. It's a student project and both procedures must be common to everyone. I add it in the topic.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Morever, I'd like to add that the server and the client are independent. It's mainly why I can't pass the structure in argument of the functions.

Comment: *Note that I can't modify the initialize() and the finalize() procedures.*  If a specific shared object can be loaded more than once, I don't see how that can work.  Offhand, it looks to be a fundamentally broken design.  There's no way for the shared object code to know *which* player is being referenced.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I see... A group in my class has used a quite awful _(in my opinion)_ method. They copy/paste and rename the library and load it. Thus, it's not the same handle, etc... I was actually looking for a better method.

Comment: @titimlb *A group in my class has used a quite awful (in my opinion) method. They copy/paste and rename the library and load it.*  Ouch. I foresee all kinds of problems. Even if you get distinct copies of the library loaded (and offhand I'm not sure that you do...), the *symbols* from each copy of the library will all have the same name. I don't even want to try unraveling the dynamically-linked utter mess that's going to result.  There's no reason I can think of to load the shared object multiple times.

Comment: Either yourself or your teacher have misunderstood something: `initialize` should return `pl` otherwise it makes no sense to allocate it. The definition of `client` should be `struct client { struct player *(*initalize)(void); void (*finalize)(struct player *); ... }`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Finally, I tried this solution and it works... I compile the same library with different names and load each file.